# Como pegar posição do Objeto (indice)

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Como pegar a posição do objeto que foi encontrado no $.inArray() ?

```
    var obj = [
    {
        cidade : [
            {
                nome : "Maringá" ,
                uf : "PR" ,
            } ,

            {
                nome : "Curitiba" ,
                uf : "PR" ,
            } ,

            {
                nome : "Londrina" ,
                uf : "PR" ,
            }
        ]
    } ,
    {
        estado : [
            {
                nome : "Paraná" ,
                sigla : "PR"  ,
                regiao : "sul"
            } ,
            {
                nome : "São Paulo" ,
                sigla : "SP"  ,
                regiao : "sul"
            } ,
            {
                nome : "Rio Grande do Sul" ,
                sigla : "PR"  ,
                regiao : "sul"
            }
        ]
    }
];
    exemplo.init();
```

Comment: Pode explicar melhor? quer saber a posição / index do objeto que tem um certo nome dentro da array "estado" por exemplo?

Comment: Douglas pode explicar melhor a pergunta? está pouco claro o que pretende fazer. Explicando melhor vai ter uma resposta mais acertada também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

faça assim:

```
function procurar(objeto_, procurado_) {    
    var encontrou = false;
    var retorno = [];   
    function recursiva(objeto)
    {               
        if(typeof objeto === 'object')
        {
            for(var i in objeto)
            {
                retorno.push(i);                
                recursiva(objeto[i]);               
                if(encontrou)
                {
                    break;
                }
                retorno.pop();
            }
        }
        else
        {           
            if(objeto === procurado_)
            {
                encontrou = true;
            }
        }       
    }   
    recursiva(objeto_); 
    return retorno;
}
```

depois crie uma função para testar:

```
function testa_procurar() {
    var procurado = 'Londrina';
    var localizacao = procurar(obj, procurado);
    console.log('localizacao: ' + localizacao); 
}
```

saída: 0,cidade,2,nome

Aí é só implementar outras funcionalidades!

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, me serviu muito bem.

Comment: E se quisesse adicionar mais um objeto Cidade, ou mais um objeto estado, como faria com hook state?

Answer (score 3):

Como descrito na [documentação](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) do `$.inArray()`, quando encontra o elemento ele retorna a posição em que ele se encontra, caso o elemento não exista ele retorna `-1`.

Comment: Entao, se ele encontrar, o retorno vai ser a posiçao do array, isso ?

Comment: Sim, mas lembrando que ele vai buscar apenas dentro do array, não funciona caso queira buscar objeto dentro de objeto.